# Error in nonlinearmodel fit for a function with Definite Integral and complex number

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting

I am trying to fit a function [image: fun] and Here is the code which I am trying, Please find the data here [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QdpXKCiz0KKr9VRS-qUwxOd9kaZhNvhQ/view?usp=sharing)

```
    Data = Import["E:\\datat.asc"];
    real = Data[[All, {1, 2}]];
    imag = Data[[All, {1, 3}]];
    w = 1.26*10^8;
    k = 1.38*10^-23;

   dynamicReal[T_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ,t_?NumericQ] := A*(1 - (NIntegrate[(((1/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*s*H))*Exp[(-(Log[(H/d)])^2/(2*s^2))]))/((1 + (w^2*t^2*Exp[((2*H)/(k*T))]))), {H, 0, 6*10^-22}]))
    dynamicImag[T_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ,t_?NumericQ] := A (NIntegrate[(w*t*Exp[H/(k*T)] (((1/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*s*H))*Exp[(-(Log[(H/d)])^2/(2*s^2))])))/((1 + (w^2*t^2*Exp[((2*H)/(k*T))]))), {H, 0, 6*10^-22}])    
    fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][Rationalize[{real, imag}, 0], {dynamicReal[T, s, d, A, t],dynamicImag[T, s, d, A, t]}, Rationalize[{{t, 1.0*10^-12}, {s, 0.25}, {d, 8*10^-23}, {A, 1.0*10^-4}}, 0], {T}]
    fit["ParameterTable"]

    Show[ListPlot[{real, imag}], Plot[{fit[1, x], fit[2, x]}, {x, 0, Max[real[[All, 1]], imag[[All, 1]]]}, PlotRange -> All], PlotRange -> All
```

I am getting an error called integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try 
increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral 
may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option

Comment: Your edit may have introduced an error in the definition of `dynamicImag`.  Instead of the imaginary unit `I` in the numerator of the integrand, I think you need `Exp[H/(k*x)]`

Comment: Have you tried getting regular plots of `dynamicReal` and `dynamicImag` with some reasonable values of s, d, A and t? It's always a good way to check that your fitting functions are behaving correctly.

Comment: Please. What is the expression for $\tau\left(E,T\right)$ ?

Comment: @Cesareo, sorry about that. I have edited the question.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I tried the regular plot of dynamicReal and dynamicImag function and I am getting reasonable plot, but while fitting I am getting an error "Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral."

Comment: Did you try to change the integration method? For example `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"` for _some problems_ works better than the default  `"GlobalAdaptive"`.

Answer (score 1):

The `ComplexExpand[ReIm @ ...]` trick doesn't work here because it doesn't evaluate to a list. You will need to re-phrase your problem as two separate functions that return the real and imaginary part of your model. So it should look something like:

```
dynamicReal[x_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[...];
dynamicImag[x_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[...];
```

Then you call the fit as:

```
fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][
   Rationalize[{real, imag}, 0], 
   {dynamicReal[x, s, d, A, t]], dynamicImag[x, s, d, A, t]]},
   ...
]
```

It shouldn't be to difficult to split the integrand in `NIntegrate` into real and imaginary parts like this.

Comment: @Sjored Smit. Thanks a lot for the help. I have edited the code but still getting the same error.